# Unable to access the SharePoint 2013 site with intranet URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

[image]

I have created a publishing site and added the alternate URL as shown in the image.

I have added the binding in IIS as shown in below

[image] 
I am unable to access the site with the intranet URL.

can any one help me to resovle this issue.

Thanks,

regards.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add the binding to the web application in IIS.

[Here](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO9987.html) is an article with screenshots that shows how to do it.

And besides that, you need to make sure that there is a dns entry that points the "spintranet" to the SharePoint machine.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have added the binding as shown in the image. Please correct me if i did wrong. I don't have any idea on dns entry. can you please provide any steps to setup dns?

Comment: You should change the port to 80 for that new binding and check if it works again.